# Mysql Workbench - Display String Values Instead of Integers In ERD Tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[Access ERD Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcYmE.png)

Still learning and would be grateful for help from you guys.

I have created a relational DB table using Access for stock management. In the process of creating links amongst the tables, i used a look-up wizard to create a combo-box selection type for the foreign keys which are of Integer types in all of the tables. In the process of using the look-up wizard, i had an option of either displaying the foreign keys as values i.e using their ID values which are of integer types or displaying them as Strings i.e using the FK's string values.

For instance in the image above, all the category_ID columns have their integer ID's but i don't want to display the integer values. I instead opted for their corresponding string values.

I have replicated the same ERD's in Mysql Workbench. This time round i am populating the tables with an Excel Userform that has combo-boxes populated by the foreign key corresponding string values.

My question is, how do i display the corresponding string values of the FK's instead of the integer values in my Mysql Workbench just like i have done using Access.

I tried inputting the FK values using their corresponding string values but had a value mismatch error.